# How Do I Add a Line Break After a Dropdown Menu

Tags: html, forms, html-select, line-breaks

I'm learning HTML, and while messing around with forms and dropdown menus, I found that I can't seem to add a line break after a dropdown. [Here is what the page looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DU7zG.png)

Adding a line break after the closing  tag doesn't appear to work, and adding multiple line breaks doesn't appear to work either. Is there any way to get the first radio button under the dropdown with pure HTML? Here is my code:

```
<form>
    <label for="dropdown" id="dropdown-label">Select one:</label><br>
        <select name="thing" id="dropdown">
          <option value="thing1">Thing 1</option>
          <option value="thing2">Thing 2</option
        </select><br>
            
    <div>
        <input type="radio" id="num1" name="choices" value="num1">
        <label for="num1">Num1</label><br>
            
        <input type="radio" id="num2" name="choices" value="num2">
        <label for="num2">Num2</label><br>  
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**thing 2 option tag was not closed. that's why br tag was not working.**

```html
<form>
    <label for="dropdown" id="dropdown-label">Select one:</label><br>
        <select name="thing" id="dropdown">
          <option value="thing1">Thing 1</option>
          <option value="thing2">Thing 2</option>
        </select>
        <br>
    <div>
    
        <input type="radio" id="num1" name="choices" value="num1">
        <label for="num1">Num1</label><br>
            
        <input type="radio" id="num2" name="choices" value="num2">
        <label for="num2">Num2</label><br>  
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

A dropdown element has it's css 'inline' by default. As you asked for a pure HTML answer, I'd put the `label` and the `dropdown` inside a div too (as they're `display: block` by default and will break). Eg:

```html
<form>
    <div>
        <label>...</label>
        <select>...</select>
    </div>
    <div>
        ...
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

using bootstrap you can add this and you are going to have a line between all menu options or after them.
`<div class="dropdown-divider"></div>`